# Error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'HomeBloc' in type cast al cargar Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito ayuda con un bloc que al parecer no está disparando el método fetch con el que llamo a una API.

El error que estoy recibiendo es:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER ╞═══════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'HomeBloc' in type cast
```

Adjunto código de bloc, métodos de clases, main y widgets.

```
part 'home_event.dart';
part 'home_state.dart';

class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  final PlayerService _playerService;

  HomeBloc(this._playerService) : super(HomeLoadingState()) {
    on<LoadApiEvent>((event, emit) async {
      final player = await _playerService.fetchHomeData();
      emit(HomeLoadedState(player.playerId, player.playerName,
          player.playerPoints, player.playerEmail, player.playerAlbums));
    });
  }
}

part of 'home_bloc.dart';

abstract class HomeEvent extends Equatable {
  const HomeEvent();
}
class LoadApiEvent extends HomeEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}


part of 'home_bloc.dart';

abstract class HomeState extends Equatable {
  const HomeState();
}

class HomeLoadingState extends HomeState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class HomeLoadedState extends HomeState {
  final int playerId;
  final String playerName;
  final String playerPoints;
  final String playerEmail;
  final List<PlayerAlbum> playerAlbums;

  const HomeLoadedState(this.playerId, this.playerName, this.playerPoints,
      this.playerEmail, this.playerAlbums);

  @override
  List<Object> get props =>
      [playerId, playerName, playerPoints, playerEmail, playerAlbums];
}
```

Adjunto código de main y widget del home, en donde se utiliza el provider:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


    return MaterialApp(
        home: MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => PlayerService(),
        ),
      ],
      child: HomePageView(),
    ));
```

Este es el widget del home page que dibuja el contenido del bloc:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => HomeBloc(
        RepositoryProvider.of<PlayerService>(context),
      )..add(LoadApiEvent()),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade800,
        appBar: const CustomAppBar(title: "LaminApp"),
        bottomNavigationBar: CircularBottomNavigation(
          tabItems,
          selectedCallback: (int? selectedPos) {
            print("clicked on $selectedPos");
          },
          selectedPos: selectedPos,
          barBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is HomeLoadedState) {
                    return Text(
                      state.playerName,
                      style: CustomTextStyle.cardItemTextStyle,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container();
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Comment: El error te lo está dando el provider, en realidad. A mí me suena más a que no estás inyectado el bloc con BlocProvider. De todos modos, estás proveyendo poca información para poder ayudarte. Quizás vendría bien que añadas un poco más de información.

Comment: Gracias Manuel!!! El problema es que no puedo agregar más código al detalle...

Comment: @RobertoHermosillaF sí podés, solo que tenés que agregar un [repro] (énfasis en mínimo), no tooodo el código que tenés. Con _más información_ se refiere a la descripción del problema, no a más código.

Comment: En este caso, creo que era necesario agregar más código para poder localizar el error, @padaleiana, no obstante, muy acertado tu link. Te doy mi más 1 a tu comentario. Creo que encontré el error, así que procederé a dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema:**

El package Flutter_Bloc usa el package Bloc, que a su vez usa el package Provider y provider usa el context (BuildContext) para propagar clases a través de la app. Es como un inyector de dependencias.

*¿Cuál es el problema entonces?*

Que no puedes usar a provider, por ende, las instancias de Bloc tampoco, en el mismo contexto en el que lo inyectas. En tu caso:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Inyectamos el bloc dentro del método build de este widget.
    // por tanto, no podemos acceder a él dentro de este contexto,
    // ya que todavía no se ha propagado.
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => HomeBloc(
        RepositoryProvider.of<PlayerService>(context),
      )..add(LoadApiEvent()),
              // Dentro del mismo contexto, estamos intentando acceder
              // al bloc que acabamos de inyectar, pero el contexto
              // todavía no se ha refrescado, por ende, no podemos 
              // acceder al bloc
              BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                },
              ),
```

*Solución:*

Refrescar el context. ¿Cómo?

Sencillamente, extrae la parte del BlocBuilder a su propio widget, de esa forma crear otro stateless widget, con su propio método build, que ya es un contexto diferente, y podrá acceder al bloc inyectado.

Otra opción es usar el widget [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html)

```dart
Center(
  child: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Text('foo');
  ),
)
```

Este widget se ofrece un parámetro context que puedes usar en lugar del context del método build, dicho context estaría refrescado.

Comment: Gracias por toda la ayuda brindada Manuel!